# How to append a font awesome icon to container

Tags: javascript

I have a button that creates two input fields when someone clicks on the add button. I want to add a font awesome icon right next to the second input field. I tried adding it by using `appendChild` and `innerHTML` but that doesn't work at all I just don't get the icon rendered, how can I do it? Here is my code:

```
const mainParent = document.getElementById('main-parent');

  const newPlatformNameInput1 = document.createElement("input");
  newPlatformNameInput1.id = index + '_first';
  newPlatformNameInput1.classList.add("form-control");
  newPlatformNameInput1.classList.add("input");
  const newPlatformNameInput2 = document.createElement("input");
  newPlatformNameInput2.id = index + '_second';
  newPlatformNameInput2.classList.add("form-control");
  newPlatformNameInput2.classList.add("input");


  const wrapperParent = document.createElement('div');
  wrapperParent.id = index + '_parent';
  wrapperParent.appendChild(newPlatformNameInput1);
  wrapperParent.appendChild(newPlatformNameInput2);

  mainParent.appendChild(wrapperParent);
  mainParent.appendChild('<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>');
```

Comment: Why not follow the approach you've followed with adding you other elements, and create an `i` element, set its classes appropriately, and then append it?

Comment: I did not downvote, but in the example code you _are_ doing something perplexing-- you've abandoned the approach that worked for all previous code and tried something that [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) does not support-- namely, passing it an html string.  It seems perhaps you've confused it with [jQuery's `.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/).  On its face, it might seem that perhaps you do not understand the code you have posted, and that may have been interpreted as a lack of research.

Comment: I didn't downvote either but people are trying to claim it is a typo. Although I believe it isn't a typo but a learning experience to understand what `appendChild` expects to be passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AppendChild expects a node to be passed not plain HTML.

```
icon = document.createElement("i");
icon.setAttribute("class","fas fa-trash");
mainParent.appendChild(icon);
```